# GWT links into an application that have different results among different links

Tags: gwt, redirect, hyperlink

I am making a GWT application. And I would like my users to recieve emails with links corresponding to dynamically generated pages, from ids. Is there a way to give them a link, in which the application reads the url, and acts on the url string, to do different things, i.e., if the link corresponded to page 1, then

```
www.mycompany.com/#page1
```

would go and load up page 1 in my gwt app. Or even something along the lines of,

```
www.mycompany.com/specficentrypoints/#page1
```

would load up that page, and the regular entry point would be left alone.

Is this even possible, if it is how could I go about doing it? Is there any tutorial, or even a brief description would help.

If there isn't, could I hack it somehow? Using some other layer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The new way of creating links to dynamic pages is with "hash bang" (`#!`) to support [google indexing](https://developers.google.com/webmasters/ajax-crawling/docs/specification).

```
wwww.mycompany.com/#!page1
```

Check out GWT Activities and Places -- a "place" is just a dynamic "page".

See: https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideMvpActivitiesAndPlaces

Comment: Also, check out the `gwt-places` tag here on stack overflow. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gwt-places

Comment: So I am already implementing something very similar to this. Yet this does not seem to help. To my understanding once the person is inside the application I have no problem redirecting them there. But can I send someone the link www.mycompany.com/#!page1, and the history interceptor will get fired? With the token of page1?

Comment: Yes! [This section](https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideMvpActivitiesAndPlaces#Putting_it_all_together) does exactly that using the method `historyHandler.handleCurrentHistory();` from within an `EntryPoint`